# only specific corner radius to UIView with constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, cornerradius

[image] snap shot before applying corner radius to some corner

i code these to get corner radius

```
extension UIView{
func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    layer.mask = mask
}
```

this is how i am applying radius because i have constrain tooo

```
import UIKit
```

class SenderCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var senderMsg: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var backView: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    senderMsg.sizeToFit()
}

func setData(reciverTime: String, reciverMsg: String ){
    senderMsg.sizeToFit()
    self.senderMsg.text = reciverMsg
    self.time.text = reciverTime
}

override func  layoutSubviews() {
    backView.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight, .topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: 5)
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

this is. an custom cell for table view

but after doing this is how i am getting radius[image]

what should i do can anyone explain ...

Comment: why it is devoted is there issue with the explanation of question i can improve it

Comment: Your post ***may*** be getting down-voted because you are not providing much information about what you're doing. Please take a few moments to review [ask]. Are you showing us table view cells? Where are you putting the `override func layoutSubviews()` code (in what class)?

Comment: and i also noticed that when i click on that cell than UIView shows how it should be i don't that what is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have much better results if you use a custom `UIView` subclass and let **it** handle its layout.

For example:

```
class BackView: UIView {
    var corners: UIRectCorner = []
    var radius: CGFloat = 5
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Then, in Storyboard / Interface Builder, set the Custom Class of the view in your cell to `BackView`, and connect the `@IBOutlet` like this:

```
@IBOutlet var backView: BackView!
```

Now, in `awakeFromNib()`, set the corners:

```
backView.corners = [.topRight, .topLeft, .bottomLeft]
```

Comment: that worked perfeclty but why do i have to make custom subclass of uiview ? and why can i use the way i did ? can you explain

Comment: In your original code, it's possible it would work if you call `super.layoutSubviews()` before `backView.roundCorners(corners:...)`. You don't **have to** use a custom view... but doing it that way ensures the mask will be updated properly, and it puts that functionality where it really belongs.